# How to log through in Blade view array of nested collection in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, collections, laravel-blade

I am using groupBy and getting this result in controller

```
$this->savedTimers = TimeLog::where('id',23)
        ->join('projects', 'projects.id', '=', time_logs.project_id')
        ->select('projects.project_name', 'time_logs.*')
        ->orderByDesc('created_at')
        ->get();
$this->savedTimers = $savedData->groupBy('project_id')->all();
```

[image]

and when i tried to loop through in blade like this

```
         @forelse($savedTimers as $key=>$groupTimer)
            @foreach($groupTimer as $timer)                    
                <div class="row">                            
                    <div class="card card-fluid">
                        <h2>
                            Group
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
         @empty
            <div class="card card-fluid"><h2>No Record</h2></div>
        @endforelse
```

getting this error

```
Property [created_at] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

can somebody helpe me to get out of this

Comment: try {{$timer->created_at}}
This might resolve the issue.

Comment: where to put this for resolving this issue. because this is not my issue i am not consoling this

Comment: use get() instead of all()

Comment: i have put whole query plz check and suggest me

Comment: if i am grouping wrongly plz guide me also

Comment: Convert it into an array using  `$savedTimers->toArray()` ;

Comment: i have attached screenshot does it not an array ?
i tried & got this "Call to a member function toArray() on array"

Comment: Do you use ->created_at somewhere in your blade? That property is not present in your collection or data, that's why Laravel throws an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check your table in database and see that `created_at` column exists or not.

And at the same time check your model also, that your `public $timestamps = false` or not. Because if it is false or commented then `created_at` and `updated_at` columns will not be created in table.

If all goes well.

Check:**->orderBy('created_at','desc')**

```
$this->savedTimers = TimeLog::where('id',23)
        ->join('projects', 'projects.id', '=', time_logs.project_id')
        ->select('projects.project_name', 'time_logs.*')
        ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
        ->get();
$this->savedTimers = $savedData->groupBy('project_id')->all();
```